# Find and Replace every instances of string with Wildcards

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, find, wildcard

I would like to find and replace a certain pattern in word using VBA. More specifically I would like to find every instance of "Table" followed by a whitespace followed by one or more digits followed by another whitespace and replace it with "Table", the same number, a period and a tab. I tried using the Find and Replace function of VBA with the "MatchWildcard" property set to true. Finding the pattern has been no problem, however I can't figure out how to replace the text, so that the number stays the same. My idea was to use the same wildcard in the replacement string, but in this case it just spells out the wildcard as text. Therefore my question is whether there is any way to use the matched value in the replacement string.

```
toFind = "Table [1-9]@ " & vbTab
Dim replacementStr As String
replacementString = "Table [1-9]@." & vbTab
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=toFind, replaceWith:=replacementStr, _
Replace:=wdReplaceAll, MatchWildcards:=True
```

Should produce: "Table 1 " -> "Table 1.  "
Does produce: "Table 1 " -> "Table [1-9]@.  "

Answer (score 0):

For further detail on using wildcards see: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

```
toFind = "(Table [1-9])@ " & vbTab
Dim replacementStr As String
replacementStr = "\1." & vbTab
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=toFind, replaceWith:=replacementStr, _
Replace:=wdReplaceAll, MatchWildcards:=True
```